# Generate a unique set of complete undirected graphs from a tibble of nodes and sets

Tags: r, igraph, tidygraph

I have a `tibble` like this:

```
Nodes <- tibble(
  Set = c("A","A","A","B","B","C"),
  name = c(1,2,3,4,6,5)
)
```

I want to generate a graph that has `Nodes` as `nodes` set and

```
Edges <- tibble(
from = c(1,1,4),
to = c(2,3,6)
)
```

as `edges`. Of course I want to generalize this process for any `Nodes`. I think that I can code this with `purrr`, but I expect `igraph` to be faster and less tricky.

Theoretically, it would be nothing really different than:

```
Nodes %>% group_as(Set) %>% complete_graph(by = "name")
```

but I am not sure that a command like `complete_graph()` exists. It exists `play_islands()`, but it works differently and it assumes that `n(Set)` would be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `make_full_graph` from `igraph`

```
with(
  Nodes,
  do.call(
    rbind,
    Map(
      function(v) {
        get.data.frame(
          set_vertex_attr(
            make_full_graph(length(v)),
            name = "name", value = v
          )
        )
      },
      split(name, Set)
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
    from to
A.1    1  2
A.2    1  3
A.3    2  3
B      4  6
```